# Installing packages on google colab using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run a bash file "run.sh" on google colab that contains the following code:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow=={1.14}
wget -P weights https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights
python detect.py $1
```

Running this throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow=={1.2} (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow=={1.2}
```

However, running the following code in a google colab cell works just fine.

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow 
!pip install tensorflow=={1.14}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just specifying one of the lists that the error message shows?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already tried that, but it throws the same error.@Braiam

Comment: And, also it doesn't explain why `! pip install tensorflow=={1.14}` works just fine, when it is run independently in a cell, instead of a bash file.

Comment: Don't use curly braces (`{1.14}`) around the version number of tensorflow. Just `1.14` as the version number would do the job.

Comment: Thanks for answering, removing the braces did the job, however can you explain why this works when even the code `bash pip install tensorflow=={1.14}` works fine in google colab.@Reza

Comment: Honestly, don't know the answer now. But I'll update my answer when I found the reason why.

Comment: Okay, thanks once again for the answer.@Reza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use curly braces (`{1.14}`) around the version number of `tensorflow`. Just `1.14` as the version number would do the job.